# Does traditional vi (not vim) have large file support?

Tags: vi, large-files, ex

Is there a way to compile traditional Vi (ex) with large-file (3+ GB) support?

I'm trying to open a file that is around 3.5GBs in size and Vi simply says: `Tmp file too large`.  If large-file support isn't a thing, is there a way to specify a larger temporary file size somewhere within the source code of Vi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

short: no

long: the limit is predefined, but the number depends on which system/version (and who said it).  But it is built into the source-code and cannot be "fixed".

As a workaround, you could use `split` to make pieces which are small enough to edit with `vi`.

But if you are suggesting *compiling* `vi`, `vim` might be suitable.

That used to be an FAQ.  For further reading:

- [When using vi to edit a large file, what should I do if I get the "not enough space" error message?](https://kb.iu.edu/d/akqv)
- [VI Tmp File Too Large Error](http://unix.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/comp.unix.solaris/2005-11/0300.html) (2005 thread on *comp.unix.solaris*)
- [16bit code in Solaris?](http://www.winface.com/any/tips_35.html) (refers to Solaris9; the limit is higher in later releases)
- [How to edit multi-gigabyte text files? Vim doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908575/how-to-edit-multi-gigabyte-text-files-vim-doesnt-work)

For source code, start here (on illumos-gate):

- [/usr/src/cmd/vi/port/ex_temp.h](https://github.com/illumos/illumos-gate/blob/master/usr/src/cmd/vi/port/ex_temp.h)
- [/usr/src/cmd/vi/port/ex_temp.c](https://github.com/illumos/illumos-gate/blob/master/usr/src/cmd/vi/port/ex_temp.c)

Comment: So there's a setting somewhere within Vi's source code that determines this and not some system limit?

Comment: Not just a "setting".  You can see better by reading the source-code.